# specific details, concrete description

Tags: idiomatic-language

How to say that specific, concrete details are not required?

> Please avoid **specific details** and provide just a general description.
>
> Please avoid **concrete details** and provide just a general description
>
> Please avoid **concrete description**.

Does the bold parts sound idiomatic? If not, then could you please provide a more natural phrase?

Comment: You would just say *specific, concrete details are not required*. As you did in your question. Note that the three sentences you provide *prohibit* those things in bold, which is something different. Not requiring something generally means that you don't *have* to do something—but that you can if you wish; it's optional. With your sentences, you're saying it's neither required *nor permitted*. So, none of your sentences convey the same meaning.

Comment: Yes, it's OK. The question is primarily about bold phrases. I wasn't sure about them. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contrasting pair of words you are looking for are "specific" and "general." The opposite of "concrete" is "abstract." However, I am not sure that the contrast between general and specific is what you really want.

This is an idiomatic expression

> Please avoid specific details and provide a general description

as is

> Please provide a general description

However, if what you really want is something that is concise and avoids excessive detail, why not say

> Please provide a concise, general description that avoids excessive detail.

Answer (score 3):

I would use 1 and 2.

You could also use:

> Please avoid **an in-depth description** and provide just a general description
>
> Please avoid **providing a lot of details** and provide just a general description
>
> Please don't **provide details** and provide just a general description